# What is the standard method for posting variable length child deletions to an asp.net MVC application?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, entity-framework, razor

I have a form with a one to many relationship.  Something like this, where a person can have multiple addresses.
[image: parent child data]

I want to allow the user to delete an address.  Without using ajax, what is the typical method for posting the appropriate model's identification to the server?

What are the drawbacks to attempting something like this?

The "delete" button is included in an editor template which displays the child model.  So I am able to include the correct model's ID in the button's value and post it.

```
<button type="submit" name="action" value="@Model.AddressID">Delete</button>
```

Then, in my main edit view, I include the "Submit" button, which has the same name.

```
<input name="action" type="submit" value="Edit"/>
```

And, last, the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(PersonViewModel person, string action)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if(editSubmit == "Edit")
            {
                //update the models
            }
            else
            {
                // delete the child models whose ID == action
            }

            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(addressEdited);
    }
```

I am doing this as a learning exercise.  I realize that, for posting data with this structure, most people are using JavaScript, and probably a framework, to organize and post the data via AJAX.